# Mongoose .save() not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this piece of code that is not working. I'm trying to save a user document after modifying it with an `ObjectId` (by adding this to an array). However, the `user.save()` is never executed (I know this because the document doesn't change in the db) and neither is the callback/promise. The `Voot` is however being saved.

I have tried tweaking around with the callbacks and promises but it didn't work out. Does anyone know what to do?

Here is the code:

(to avoid confusion, note that the `handleError()` and `sendJson()` functions are custom functions made by me)

```
// Create new voot
var newVoot = Voot({
    title,
    body,
    user: userId,
    is_public,
    create_date
});
newVoot.save().then((voot) => {
    User.findById(userId, (err, user) => {
        handleError(err, 400, res);
        if (user) {
            user.voots.push(voot._id);
            // This console log shows me the correct modified user document
            console.log(user);
            user.save().then(() => {
                // This console.log and sendJson does not get executed
                console.log("User object is saved");
                sendJson(200, {voot}, res);
            }).catch((err) => {
                // This console log does not get executed
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You're not handling promise rejections correctly. *user.save() is never executed (I know this because the document doesn't change in the db)* - this is wrong. It's obviously executed but likely isn't succeeded. You need to have `.catch` for *all* promises you have (that you use callbacks for User.findById and promises for user.save makes control flow more error-prone.

Comment: Good suggestion, I just added a .catch(), however, this does not show any errors.

Comment: Instead of use a select and after that a save, use the mongoose update method. Something like that: User.update({ _id: userId }, { $push: { voots: voot._id } }).then...

Comment: This worked! Could you rewrite this as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`User.findById(userId, (err, user) => ...` has two params in its callback function: `err` and `user`.

`user` is the document returned from MongoDB, meaning it's a normal Javascript object and thus you can't call `.save()` on it.

For this use case you could use Mongoose's [findbyIdAndUpdate()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate), which will do both of the operations you need to the `User` model. Just remember to give `{ upsert: true }` as an options object to make sure you create a new document if it doesn't already exist.

Example

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({ id }, { update1: 'value' }, { upsert: true }, (err, result) => {
  // handle result
})
```

Comment: If `User` is a mongoose model, then `user` returned from `User.findById` will be a mongoose document, `.save()` will be available.

Comment: When using callbacks, the second parameter is just the results of the query.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether using callbacks or promises, the result will be mongoose document by default, unless `lean` option is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use a select and after that a save, use the mongoose update method. Something like that: User.update({ _id: userId }, { $push: { voots: voot._id } }).then...